# How to find the mean value of noramlly distributed number?

Tags: java

First of all, I know how to find the mean right. So now my program description is- I am using a method name **nextGaussian** to get the normally distributed number, this method is working fine. I also used the **CONSOLE SCREEN** to check  the normally distributed number curve. After when I am trying to find the mean(Average) value, it give me error,

1.For example suppose we have five numbers(30,50,60,70,80)

- First of all I need to find the total of them, and divide them by 5 right, but in my program, it takes the last number and divide this number by 5, means it takes the 80, and divide this number by 5

2.If you want any additional information, please leave a comment, I will do that...

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;;
public class NormalNumberProblem extends JFrame 
{
    static JTextField a = new JTextField();
    static JButton x = new JButton();

  public static void main(String args[]) 
  {
    // construct frame
    new NormalNumberProblem().show();
  }
  public NormalNumberProblem() 
  {
    // frame constructor
    setTitle("NormalNumberProblem");

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    getContentPane().setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    GridBagConstraints gridConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    a.setText("");
    a.setColumns(15);
    gridConstraints.gridx = 0;
    gridConstraints.gridy = 1;
    getContentPane().add(a, gridConstraints);

    x.setText("Random Numbers");
    gridConstraints.gridx =0;
    gridConstraints.gridy =3;
    getContentPane().add(x, gridConstraints);
    x.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
                {
                Random r = new Random();
                double[] list = new double[15];
                double mean = 10, std = 50;

                for(int i = 0; i<list.length; i++)
                {
                    double sum = 0;;
                    list[i] = r.nextGaussian() * 10 + 50;

                    sum += sum + list[i];
                    System.out.println(sum); 
                    double average = sum / list.length;
                    a.setText(" The mean is " + NumberFormat.getNumberInstance().format(average));   
                }
        }

        });

    pack();
    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    setBounds((int) (0.5 * (screenSize.width - getWidth())), (int) (0.5 * (screenSize.height - getHeight())), getWidth(), getHeight());
  }


}
```

Thanks....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move some of the elements out of the loop (otherwise you redefine your `sum` each iteration and at the end it is just the last number):

```
double sum = 0;
double average = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
                {
                    list[i] = r.nextGaussian() * 10 + 50;
                    sum = sum + list[i];
                    System.out.println(sum); 
                }

average = sum / list.length;
a.setText(" The mean is " + NumberFormat.getNumberInstance().format(average));
```

Comment: @CRazyProgrammer: No it doesn't. It does not fix the second bug I've pointed out (and fixed) in my answer.

Comment: which one, "the values of a normally distributed number"

Comment: +1, the sum was wrong, @NPE answer is correct.

Comment: I am confused, what you mean by answer is correct, I calculated , but it seems right...

Comment: I edited my answer, it should work as it is now, I'm not sure which version did you use. You had 'sum += sum + list[i];' which is not what you need because it is equivalent to 'sum = sum + sum + list[i];'. What you meant to have is 'sum = sum + list[i]' or 'sum += list[i]'. Hope it helps :)

Comment: yes, answer that it is giving is incorrect

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the loop as follows:

```
            double sum = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i<list.length; i++)
            {
                list[i] = r.nextGaussian() * 10 + 50;
                sum += list[i];
                System.out.println(sum); 
            }
            double average = sum / list.length;
            a.setText(" The mean is " + NumberFormat.getNumberInstance().format(average));
```

Here, I've moved `sum` and `average` out of the loop, and have fixed a bug in `sum += sum + list[i]` (you don't need both `+=` and `sum +`).